# How do I call and parse postgres user-defined types

Tags: java, postgresql, user-defined-types

I made the following user-defined type in my postgres db:

```
create type var_data as
(
var1 varchar,
var2 varchar,
var3 character varying[]
);
```

And I want to call a function in postgres called `get_var` that will return that udt. I want to get the information stored within the returned udt. I wrote the following Java code to both connect to the db and then parse the result.

```
public Var getVar(int number) throws SQLException
{
    try (Connection connection = dataSource().getConnection()
    ) {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{? = call get_var(?) }");
        //callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.OTHER); <-- This didn't work
        //The following was what I saw online
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.STRUCT, "var_data");
        callableStatement.setInt(2, number);

        logger.info("About to execute getVar");
        callableStatement.execute();
        logger.info("Got data back from the db, about to parse it");
        ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(1);
        Var var = null;
        while (rs.next()){
            String var1= rs.getString("var1");
            String var2= rs.getString("var2");
            String[] var3= (String[]) rs.getArray("var3").getArray();
            var = new Var(var1, var2, var3);
        }
        connection.setAutoCommit(true);
        return var;
    }
}
```

When I call this java code, I get the following exception: "Method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(int,int,String) is not yet implemented."

So my question is, is there a way in java to call a function that returns postgres user-defined types? If yes, can you please show me how to do so?

(Also, what is the correct way to parse the udt once I get it in represented in java?)

Comment: Please see the help section [ask]. Following that as  template is much more likely to get a satisfactory answer. Further in this case your question is ambiguous: Are you asking to retrieve the description of your udt or the data content of a column defined as the udt.

Comment: I updated my question. I originally attempted to use your template, but the result was not clear. I'm not really sure what you find unclear about this.